# Layered Navigation not visible when Display Mode set to Static Block only (2.2.5)

Tags: magento2, luma-theme

Running 2.2.5 (Luma)

In the category, when I use `Display Mode:` `Products only` or `Static block and products`, the layered navigation is clearly visible on the frontend. However, as soon as I switch to `Static block only` the Layered Navigation is no longer visible.

I've tried this on 2 seperate 2.2.5 installations. Did something change since 2.2.2 because I'm sure this used to work before upgrading.

EDIT: I just installed 2.2.2 (Luma + Sample Data) and tested. It seems this didn't used to happen.

Comment: Seems, this is normal. Whenever I select category `Display Mode: Static Block Only`. The layered navigation and products should not be visible. Because I select this mode to show only static block's contents in the category page, not products or filter.

Comment: Magento 2 Demo Data circumvented that by using `<referenceContainer name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true"/>` in the `Layout Update XML` section of the category. Perhaps this updated change is in fact by design. So that leads me to the question, How do I get it back...

Comment: @Craig I saw this behaviour return in 2.3.3 where in display mode static block only I still got layered nav, but in 2.3.4 it seems to be gone again - no layered nav. Did you ever find a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Magento core saw that functionality as a bug see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17038

In the code difference between M2.3.3 and 2.3.4 (https://github.com/magento/magento2/compare/2.3.3...2.3.4#diff-4e3e31cf219d441cb8727ac984998ad07454b20466f6bbb7d380e6a8debe1994 see `app/code/Magento/LayeredNavigation/Block/Navigation.php`) the change that "fixes" this "bug" is adding in the additional check for the category display mode

```
$this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getDisplayMode() !== \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::DM_PAGE
```

So in order to have this bug on your site, you would need to modify the `canShowBlock` method to not check the display mode.

As it is a public function, this can be easily solved with a plugin. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html